# PROBLEMA CON UPDATE SET Y WHERE PHP MVC

Tags: php, mysql, mvc

CUANDO ACTUALIZO UN PRODUCTO AL PRIMER CODIGO ME LO TOMA EN CUENTA PERO CON LOS DEMAS PRODUCTOS NO ME LO TOMA ESPERO ME PUEDAN AYUDAR ACA

if ($resultado == "ok") {

```
                $actualizarProductoStock = ControladorProductos::VerActualizarProductoStock1();

                $itemProductoID = $actualizarProductoStock["codigo"];

                $itemProductoStock = $actualizarProductoStock["total_restante"];

                $restarStock = abs($_POST["entregada"] - $actualizarProductoStock["total_restante"]);

                //var_dump($itemProductoID);

                ModeloProductos::SumarStock("productos", $itemProductoID, $restarStock);
```

}

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega tu código como texto y no como imagen. Por otra parte, las preguntas en mayúsculas se interpretan como solicitudes gritando y podría llevar a tener votos negativos. Saludos

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.